# Is there an alternative to the native file transfer handler in Finder?

Tags: finder, uti

In Windows you can replace the native file handler with TeraCopy, I was wondering if there were a similar solution in Mac OS X. Because the current handler is not that great.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Details about what you perceive to be the shortcomings of the Finder's file handler would help those of unfamiliar with the Windows utility's benefits to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend and use [UltraCopier](http://ultracopier.first-world.info/) which is the closest I found to TeraCopy.

An alternative is [ForkLift](http://www.binarynights.com), which doesn’t just handle file transfers, but lots of other stuff, too.